# tikzfadingfrompicture with fit fading=false (Potential bug)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-fadings

In the manual page 361 this is written about `fit fading`:

> /tikz/fit fading=⟨boolean⟩ (default true, initially true)
>
> When set to
> true, the fading is shifted and resized (in exactly the same way as a
> shading) so that it covers the current path. When set to **false**, the
> fading is only shifted so that it is centered on the path’s center,
> but it is not resized. This can be useful for special-purpose fadings,
> for instance when you use a fading to “punch out” something.

With `fit fading=false` the `tikzfadingfrompicture` should be shifted, so that its center is placed on the path’s center. In this example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
\fill[transparent!0] (2,2) rectangle (3,5);
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[
  path fading=myfading,
  fit fading=false,
  preaction={draw},
] (-1,-4) rectangle (7,2);
\fill[red] (0,0) circle[radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Square, filled rectangle and a red dot]

it can be seen that the `tikzfadingfrompicture` is not centered on the path’s center but on `(0,0)`. Is this a bug, or are there something I do not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot tell whether this is a bug or intended behaviour, but using `fading transform`, you can easily shift the center of the fading to the center of the current bounding box (or of whatever reference system):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
\fill[transparent!0] (2,2) rectangle (3,5);
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[
  path fading=myfading,
  fit fading=false,
  preaction={draw},
  fading transform={shift={(current bounding box.center)}} 
] (-1,-4) rectangle (7,2);

\fill[red] (0,0) circle[radius=0.1];

\fill[yellow] (current bounding box.center) circle[radius=0.1];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I still see it as a bug, but this is a perfect circumvention.