# Transparency, not opacity, is needed as fading for plotting a surface over a lattice

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, transparency, tikz-fadings

I can, to some extent, define a new color map for a 3d-surface and import some tikz picture as a node inside the 3d-plot. I want to put the 3d-surface over the inserted node object where one of the colors in the colormap should be *transparent*, while the others just appear as they should over the node object. Clearly opacity option is not what I need. I could do something similar using fading but that was not for plots of functions, but only for simple color gradients. What I have is the following, and I want to make the white transparent to put the surface over the lattice.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}
\centering

\savebox\mybox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
\fill [green!50] 
    foreach \y in {1,...,10} {
        foreach \x in {1,...,20} {
            ({.25*\x + (-1)^(\y)*0.125*.5}, .25*\y) circle [radius=.10]
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=2]
\def\a{0}
\def\b{0}
    \begin{axis} [point meta min=-1., point meta max=1.,
        colormap={emfield}{
        rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,255) rgb255(3cm)=(255,255,255) rgb255(6cm)=(255,0,0)
        },
        axis equal image,
        zmin=-1, zmax=1,
        view={0}{90}, axis lines=none]
        \addplot3 [surf, shader= interp, domain=-4*pi:4*pi, y domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=50,
            ] { ((x-\a)^2 + (y-\b)^2)^(-.5)*sin(deg(2*((x-\a)^2 + (y-\b)^2)^(.5))) };
        \node [opacity=1] at (0,0) {\usebox\mybox};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That looks like

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can use `tikzfadingfrompicture` to create a mask using the plot (but only with black and white) and than apply this mask fading to the green dots ...

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of fadings and create a fading from your plot using `tikzfadingfrompicture` which you can then apply to the green dots. This is probably not the most straight-forward approach, but I am unsure whether you can apply a fading to a plot directly.

This only shows the basic approach, because I am usure what the result should look like in the end. Probably, some adjustment of the opacity settings is needed. Also, there may be a more elegant way to achieve proper scaling and placement of the fading.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture} [xscale=.25, yscale=.5, name=plot fading]
\def\a{0}
\def\b{0}
    \begin{axis} [point meta min=-1., point meta max=1.,
        colormap={emfield}{
        rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,0) rgb255(3cm)=(255,255,255) rgb255(6cm)=(0,0,0)
        },
        axis equal image,
        zmin=-1, zmax=1,
        view={0}{90}, axis lines=none]
        \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, domain=-4*pi:4*pi, y domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=50,
            ] { ((x-\a)^2 + (y-\b)^2)^(-.5)*sin(deg(2*((x-\a)^2 + (y-\b)^2)^(.5))) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\savebox\mybox{
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1.3]
\fill [green!50] 
    foreach \y in {1,...,10} {
        foreach \x in {1,...,20} {
            ({.25*\x + (-1)^(\y)*0.125*.5}, .25*\y) circle [radius=.10]
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=2]
\def\a{0}
\def\b{0}
    \begin{axis} [point meta min=-1., point meta max=1.,
        colormap={emfield}{
        rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,255) rgb255(3cm)=(255,255,255) rgb255(6cm)=(255,0,0)
        },
        axis equal image,
        zmin=-1, zmax=1,
        view={0}{90}, axis lines=none]
        \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, domain=-4*pi:4*pi, y domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=50,
            ] { ((x-\a)^2 + (y-\b)^2)^(-.5)*sin(deg(2*((x-\a)^2 + (y-\b)^2)^(.5))) };
        \begin{scope}
            \path [scope fading=plot fading] ({-4*pi},{-2*pi}) rectangle ({4*pi},{2*pi});
            \node at (0,0) {\usebox\mybox};
        \end{scope}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For scaling and placement, you need e.g. `\path (0,0) circle[radius=10];` and then `fit fading=false`. See my answer and also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655904/tikzfadingfrompicture-with-fit-fading-false-potential-bug

Comment: Ah, thank you! I was struggling with `fit fading=false` and in the end decided to just use a scaling that fits. I was wondering whether such a fading could be applied to the plot directly, but it seems that it is not possible, not even if you place the `\addplot` command in a scope and apply the fading to that. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I just made the whole `axis` transparent - it works :o)

Answer (score 2):

As @Jasper Habicht writes, you need `tikzfadingfrompicture` for this. It is not possible to know what result you imagine. I have made the transparency steeper here:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
point meta min=-0.5, point meta max=0.5,
colormap={emfield}{color=(transparent!100) color=(transparent!100) color=(transparent!100) color=(transparent!0) color=(transparent!100) color=(transparent!100) color=(transparent!100)},
axis equal image,
axis lines=none,
]
\addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, domain=-4*pi:4*pi, y domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=50] { ((x)^2 + (y)^2)^(-.5)*sin(deg(2*((x)^2 + (y)^2)^(.5))) };
\end{axis}
\path (0,0) circle[radius=10]; %encompassing circle for alignment
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
point meta min=-1, point meta max=1,
colormap={emfield}{rgb255=(0,0,255) rgb255=(255,255,255) rgb255=(255,0,0)},
axis equal image,
axis lines=none,
]
\addplot3[surf, shader=interp, domain=-4*pi:4*pi, y domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=50] { ((x)^2 + (y)^2)^(-.5)*sin(deg(2*((x)^2 + (y)^2)^(.5))) };
\end{axis}
\fill[path fading=myfading, fit fading=false, green!50, scale=1.3] foreach \y in {1,...,10} {foreach \x in {1,...,20} {({.25*\x + (-1)^(\y)*0.125*.5}, .25*\y) circle [radius=.10]}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Code is with `samples=50`, but image is with `samples=80`:

[image: Circular pattern with green dots]

**Edit:** By comment from @Jasper Habicht, here is the plot itself made transparent instead of the green dots:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
point meta min=-0.5, point meta max=0.5,
colormap={emfield}{color=(transparent!0) color=(transparent!0) color=(transparent!0) color=(transparent!100) color=(transparent!0) color=(transparent!0) color=(transparent!0)},
axis equal image,
axis lines=none,
]
\addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, domain=-4*pi:4*pi, y domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=50] { ((x)^2 + (y)^2)^(-.5)*sin(deg(2*((x)^2 + (y)^2)^(.5))) };
\end{axis}
\path (0,0) circle[radius=10]; %encompassing circle for alignment
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green!50, scale=1.3] foreach \y in {1,...,10} {foreach \x in {1,...,20} {({.25*\x + (-1)^(\y)*0.125*.5}, .25*\y) circle [radius=.10]}};
\path[scope fading=myfading, fit fading=false] (0,0);
\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
point meta min=-1, point meta max=1,
colormap={emfield}{rgb255=(0,0,255) rgb255=(255,255,255) rgb255=(255,0,0)},
axis equal image,
axis lines=none,
]
\addplot3[surf, shader=interp, domain=-4*pi:4*pi, y domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=50] { ((x)^2 + (y)^2)^(-.5)*sin(deg(2*((x)^2 + (y)^2)^(.5))) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Red and blue circles with green dots behind]

Comment: capacity exceeded. I still don't know how to fix this for TeXMaker, Windows

Comment: Maybe your computer can not handle `samples=80`. I will change it back to 50.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works for me. Both answers are good but I need more time to look at both of them