# Create TikZ picture with (0,0) at center of page

Tags: tikz-pgf

A `tikzfadingfrompicture` is always inserted at `(0,0)`. (because of a bug? - see
[tikzfadingfrompicture with fit fading=false (Potential bug)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655904/tikzfadingfrompicture-with-fit-fading-false-potential-bug) )

When answering this question:
[Giving a Title a Gilded Effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660594/giving-a-title-a-gilded-effect/660648#660648)
I wanted to use a full page `tikzfadingfrompicture` and to do that, I need a `tikzpicture` with `(0,0)` at the center of the page.

I ended up doing this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, baseline=-1em]
\draw[red] (0,0) circle[radius=0.1];
\draw[blue] (current page) circle[radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

[image: White page with two circles]

---

The solution with

```
\centering
\vspace*{\fill} ... \vspace*{\fill}
baseline=-1em
```

is not optimal and as seen, it does not give the correct center. Is there a better way?

Comment: Shouldn't you also set `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` to avoid shifts due to unequal margins?

Comment: What about `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.center)}] \draw[red] (0,0) circle[radius=0.1]; \end{tikzpicture}`?

Comment: @JasperHabicht: Yes you are correct. In the "Gilded" question, the margins are symmetric by `\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in, vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}`. I am hoping for a solution, that works even with asymmetric margins.

Comment: It seems to work- very simple. I did not think of that. Will you make an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, shifting the whole `tikzpicture` to `(current page.center)` should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.center)}]
\draw[red] (0,0) circle[radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw[blue] (current page.center) circle[radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Shifting to `(current page)` also works, but to me, `(current page.center)` is more meaningful in this context.)

Comment: It works, but I can not make it work in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660594/giving-a-title-a-gilded-effect/660648#660648. -there are still strange things going on, that I do not understand.